# Pgfplots trimming white space problem

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to trim the white space around a 3D mesh plot. I am aware that clip is able to do the trick, but in my case, there seems to be right and bottom margins which cannot be removed, whatever I try. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{202,0,32}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{244,165,130}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{146,197,222}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{5,113,176}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-0.5,2) rectangle (6.5,6.5);
\begin{axis}[
    width=250pt,
    axis lines=none,
    ]
        \addplot3 [data cs=cart, mesh, line width=0.3pt] table [x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{y}, z expr=\thisrow{z}] {geodesic.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like. I want to trim all the white space. Would anybody be kind to help me sort this out?

[image]

Comment: I think if you draw the axis lines you can see why. Without some sample data it is difficult to say.

Comment: The file I am using to plot this is 20k lines. But I think is different from the axis lines - they extend in other directions anyway.

Comment: I don't understand John's response to @percusse's suggestion.  What happens if you change `xmax` and `ymin`?

Comment: Could you try to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` (or as new as your installation allows) and see if it changes something? the clipping has been modified some time in the past and you are running in backwards compatibility mode.

Comment: Did you try Christian's suggestion? Also, what is the point of the `\clip`?