# Remove white space around 3D pgfplots figure with no axes nor ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This question is similar to the one found here: [Pgfplots trimming white space problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324840/pgfplots-trimming-white-space-problem)

I am working on a 3D figure, generated using `pgfplots`, where I have removed axes and ticks. The problem is that, depending on the specific view, there remains a lot of white space around the figure. For example, using the code below I create my surface of interest

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ztick=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        surf, 
        color=gray!75, 
        faceted color=gray!70, 
        domain=-1:1,
        y domain=-1:1, 
    ] {-0.2*x^2-0.2*y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates the following figure:
[image]

Notice the white space above and below. Now, I know that this white space comes from the surrounding box. If I remove the lines

```
axis line style={draw=none},
tick style={draw=none},
```

from the code above, it shows the surrounding box that coincides with the surrounding white space that I want to eliminate:

[image]

Since I want to work with the option `axis equal`, modifying `zmin` and `zmax` values has little effect on the resulting image.

**How can I eliminate the surrounding white space in my figure?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal,
hide axis,
]
\addplot3[
surf, 
color=gray!75, 
faceted color=gray!70, 
domain=-1:1,
y domain=-1:1, 
] {-0.2*x^2-0.2*y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A gray curved surface]